# How to "freeze" a graphics window in R without closing it?

Tags: r, windows, graphics

How do you "freeze" a graphics window in R without closing it?
Or, put differently, **how can I start a new device without opening a new window?**

Assume I have a graphics window with par(mfrow=c(2,2)) open and it only has 3 graphics images. If I go to print a new graphics image, it will fill in that 4th slot in the open device window.

However, what if I want the next set of graphics images to show up in a new window, but I *don't* want to explicitly open a new window (right away)?

- I might not want to open a new window at the end of the 1st set of graphics commands to avoid having an 'empty' window just sitting there, or
- I might want to avoid having to explicitly call a new device at the start of a subsequent set of graphics commands (perhaps because it's much later in my code and I've forgotten I needed to do so)

**Is there a way to "finalize" a graphics window so that no additional images may be added or changed on it but in a way that doesn't close the device (or open a new window)?**

Comment: Can't you be satisfied with `layout(matrix(c(1:3,0), 2, byrow = T))` ?

Comment: why is this useful? I mean what is the purpose of your question?